# Trying to convert Excel Fuzzy logic to Python function

Tags: django, python-3.x, fuzzy-logic

I currently use the following fuzzy logic command in Excel to select a value from a reference table:
`=IF(E49>0,VLOOKUP(E49,'Ref Table'!$D$4:$E$22,2,FALSE),"--")`

I am trying to write a Django/Python function that will give the value closest to the numbers provided.  (Example: Score = 14.5 - Value returned is 0.021)

I installed fuzzywuzzy but I am not sure it is the best way to implement this.

Below is an example of the function so far without the Fuzzy Logic.

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_perc(score):
    if score is None:
        return '--'
    else:
        pct_dict = {
            14: 0.016,
            14.7: 0.021,
            15.3: 0.026,
            16: 0.034,
            16.7: 0.04,
            17.3: 0.05,
            18: 0.07,
            18.7: 0.09,
            19.3: 0.11,
            20: 0.13,
            20.7: 0.17,
            21.3: 0.21,
            22: 0.26,
            22.7: 0.31,
            23.3: 0.38,
            24: 0.47,
            24.7: 0.56,
            25.3: 0.68,
            26: 0.82,
            26.7: 0.98,
            27.3: 1.17,
            28: 1.39,
            29.3: 1.94,
            30: 2.28
        }
    if score in pct_dict.keys():
        return pct_dict[score]
    else:
        return '--'
```

(Example: Score = 14.5 - Value returned is 0.021)

Comment: Hi Brook! Welcome to SO! It's not entirely clear to me what the issue you are trying to solve is. What does your function return and how is this different from the expected output? Is your function returning the incorrect result, or would you like it to behave differently? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply trying to fuzzy match the input to one of your keys, using fuzzywuzzy, you could try something like this:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def get_perc(score):
    # I put your dictionary up here so that it's always defined.
    pct_dict = {
        14: 0.016,
        14.7: 0.021,
        15.3: 0.026,
        16: 0.034,
        16.7: 0.04,
        17.3: 0.05,
        18: 0.07,
        18.7: 0.09,
        19.3: 0.11,
        20: 0.13,
        20.7: 0.17,
        21.3: 0.21,
        22: 0.26,
        22.7: 0.31,
        23.3: 0.38,
        24: 0.47,
        24.7: 0.56,
        25.3: 0.68,
        26: 0.82,
        26.7: 0.98,
        27.3: 1.17,
        28: 1.39,
        29.3: 1.94,
        30: 2.28
    }
    MATCH_THRESHOLD = 80 # This is the minimum score needed to "match" a value
                         #  you can change it as you like.

    if not score:   # I changed this, so that any "falsey" value will return '--'
                    #   this includes values like '', None, 0, and False
        return '--'

    match, match_score = process.extractOne(score, pct_dict.keys())

    if match_score >= MATCH_THRESHOLD:
        return pct_dict[match]
    else:
        return '--'
```

I made a few changes to your original code, with explanation in comments.

I've never used fuzzywuzzy, but based this on the "Usage" section of the fuzzywuzzy README: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Comment: I am trying to get this to work but I keep getting this error:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/string_processing.py", line 26, in replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace
wnas1      |     return cls.regex.sub(" ", a_string)

Comment: I keep on running in to the same error:

Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
expected string or bytes-like object
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/string_processing.py in replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace, line 26
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path: 
['/code/bootstrap4',
 '/code',
 '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Comment: @BrookHurd, this is because the process function is likely expecting strings rather than numbers. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, you were a great help.  I also learned the data used with FuzzyWuzzy must be converted to text to work properly. I was able to enclose the data in '' and convert the incoming score using str().  I am currently looking for a method to use the str() command on the multidimensional array to eliminate the need to use '' in the data.

Here is my working code:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_perc(score):
    MATCH_THRESHOLD = 80
    pct_dict = {'14': '0.016', '14.7': '0.021', '15.3': '0.026', '16': '0.034', '16.7': '0.04', '17.3': '0.05', '18': '0.07', '18.7': '0.09', '19.3': '0.11', '20': '0.13', '20.7': '0.17', '21.3': '0.21', '22': '0.26', '22.7': '0.31', '23.3': '0.38', '24': '0.47'}
    if not score:
        return '--'
    elif score < 24:
        return '<1'

    match, match_score = process.extractOne(str(score), pct_dict.keys())

    if match_score >= MATCH_THRESHOLD:
        return pct_dict[match]
    else:
        return '--'
```